# Renaming every file in every folder in a directory with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a directory of about 60 folders of .jpg images, each of them at about 10 pictures. The problem is that in each of these directories the images are at correct order, but the names are in a whack, with some directories starting at `000.jpg`, others at `002.jpg`. What I want to do is to make a script that will rename files in every of those directories, starting at `001.jpg`.

I had a bit of success. Following is the code that works when executed in every directory.

```
$i = 1

Get-ChildItem *.jpg | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('{0:D3}.jpg' -f $i++)}
```

So I tried to make it work at a root directory instead of me executing it 60 times, each time I have to do it. And so far I failed. I tried to piece it from various pieces, but now I don't even understand what my code is supposed to do.

```
$dir = Get-ChildItem | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
$dir | Foreach-Object{
$i = 1

Get-ChildItem *.jpg | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('{0:D3}.jpg' -f $i++)}}
```

I'll be honest with you, I don't understand PowerShell much. That's why I'm asking you for help with fixing the code and making it work better.

Comment: You need to go into each folder, do the renaming, then come back out again. `$rootDir = Get-Location` at the top of the script, then for each loop `set-location $_` do the Get-ChildItem renumbering then `set-location $rootDir` to return to the origin.

Comment: You could use `Group-Object` like `Get-ChildItem .\*\*.jpg | Group Directory | ForEach-Object -Begin {$i=0} -Process {$_.Group | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('{0:D3}.jpg' -f $i++)}}}` ...I'm pretty sure that'll do what you want it to.